# I was trying to run a simulation to determine what is the standard deviation of the sum of 16 standard normal variables

Tags: r

```
2 * (1 - pnorm(z_score, mean = 0, sd = 1))
2 * (1 - pnorm(diff, mean = 0, sd = se))
```

I tried the above commands and I am new to R, please help.

Comment: Where are the 16 standard normal variables?

Comment: Can you try explaining what your question is more, so that I can help

Comment: what are diff, z_score and se?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I understand what you want to do well, the following code will work for you, assuming that standard normals are independent.

```
X <- matrix(NA, nrow = 10000, ncol = 16)
for(i in 1:16) X[,i] <- rnorm(10000)
Y <- rowSums(X)

rbind(mean = mean(Y), var = var(Y), sd = sd(Y))
            [,1]
mean  0.03440269
var  16.17512070
sd    4.02183052
```

[image]

The standard deviation will be 4 for the sum of normal (independent) variables, since the variance is the sum of the variances. And finally the standard deviation is the square root of the variance.